Paramiko: stdin.write works only if I stop at a breakpoint, doesn't work with sleep
I'm trying to run a command on a remote Linux machine with paramiko
    ssh = SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(IP_VM_AIX, PORT_VM_AIX, username=USER_VM_AIX, password=PWD_VM_AIX)

    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(
        "sftp -v " + USER_TRS2 + "@" + ADRESSE_TRS2 + " << END_SCRIPT" +
        "\nbinary" +
        "\nput " + EMPLACEMENT_BUFFER_DANS_VM_AIX + '/' + nomJcl +
        " /some/path/" + nomJcl +
        "\nbye" +
        "\nEND_SCRIPT",
        get_pty=True
    )

    #sleep(10)

    stdin.write(PWD_TRS2 + "\n")
    #stdin.channel.send(PWD_TRS2 + "\n")
    stdin.flush()

The command run with exec_command is effective only when I stop at a breakpoint (on the line with stdin.write). Even if uncomment the line with sleep (with whatever argument) it won't work.
Does anyone understand?
